# Three.js asynchronous loading issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was trying to find the maximium value of a pointcloud data as following code.

```
import { PLYLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/PLYLoader";

let max_x = -Infinity;

function initModel() {
  new PLYLoader().load("../data/division/1.ply", (geometry) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < geometry.attributes.position.count; j += 3)
      max_x = Math.max(max_x, geometry.attributes.position.array[j]);
  });
}

function print() {
  console.log(max_x);
}

initModel();
print();//got -Infinity
```

But it didn't work because `Three.js` loaded the file asynchronously. I tried a few ways to solve this problem.
I tried to add `async` and `await` before them like this.

```
import { PLYLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/PLYLoader";

let max_x = -Infinity;

async function initModel() {
  new PLYLoader().load("../data/division/1.ply", (geometry) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < geometry.attributes.position.count; j += 3)
      max_x = Math.max(max_x, geometry.attributes.position.array[j]);
  });
}

async function print() {
  await initModel();
  console.log(max_x);
}

print();//still got -Infinity
```

But I still got -Infinity, I have searched the web, but examples don't seem to do something in the callback function of `load` as I did. But `setTimeout()` worked.
Any help would be appericated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the file is being loaded asynchronously. Your second code still doesn't work because even if `initModel()` is now asynchronous, it does not await `load()`, it just calls it and returns. Since `PLYLoader.load()` is not defines as an `async` function, you also can't just await it.

I recommend to familiarize with asynchronous javascript programming in general. The easiest thing to do is just to let your logic be asynchronous too, and `print()` inside the callback, like so:

```
function initModel() {
    new PLYLoader().load("../data/division/1.ply", (geometry) => {
        for (let j = 0; j < geometry.attributes.position.count; j += 3)
            max_x = Math.max(max_x, geometry.attributes.position.array[j]);

        print();
    });
}
```

If you absolutely want some synchronous code, you can always await a promise that checks with regular time intervals whether your model has finished building. But more likely, you are going to want to do run something else meanwhile rather than to block your program waiting for this to happen. There are usually ways of adapting your program logic to asynchronous logic, and it's almost certainly better.